# How to make text appear in another textbox with jQuery with a datepicker?

Tags: jquery, html

I have input textbox that calls a datepicker and allows user to pick a date. I need the date to appear as day in another textbox. The issue is that the day textbox only fills after you pick the date and then click on the date input box again. The day textbox is not being automatically filled from the onSelect in the datepicker it seems. I need it to appear as soon as the user selects the date.

I have tried using the .on method with a focus event, and the onSelect attribute in datepicker, which should run my function for showing the day instantly....The reason am using `.on` is that the rows that contain input textboxes are loading dynamically from code-behind after the initial page loads.

```js
$('body').on('focus', ".datepickerInput", function () {
    $(this).datepicker({
        controlType: "select",
        onSelect: showDay($(this).attr("id"))
    });
});
function showDay(id) {
    var weekday = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
    var dateVal = "";
    var Day = $("#" + id).closest('tr').find('td:eq(5) input').attr('id')
    dateVal = $("#" + id).val();
    var x = new Date(dateVal);
    dayOfWeek = weekday[x.getDay()];
    $("#" + Day).val(dayOfWeek);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<table>
         <thead>
          <tr>
           <th>infoW</th>
           <th>infoX</th>
           <th>infoY</th>
           <th>infoZ</th>
          </tr>
         <thead>
         <tbody>
          <tr>
           <td>
           <input type="text asp-for="Shift0">
           </td>
           <td>
           <input type="text" asp-for="Date0" class="datepickerInput"/>
           </td>
           <td>
           <input type="text" asp-for="Time0" class="timepickerInput" />
           </td>
           <td>
           <input type="text" asp-for="Day0" />
           </td>
          </tr>
          <td>
           <input type="text asp-for="Shift1">
           </td>
           <td>
           <input type="text" asp-for="Date1" class="datepickerInput"/>
           </td>
           <td>
           <input type="text" asp-for="Time1" class="timepickerInput" />
           </td>
           <td>
           <input type="text" asp-for="Day1" />
           </td>
          <tr>
           @*..More of the same tds with different ids.*@
          </tr>
         </tbody>
        </table>
```

The day textbox should be filled with the actual day based on the date selected from date textbox when the date is selected.

Comment: You attach the event which handles your onSelect after a datePicker gets the focus. Try to initialize your datepicker with the onSelect option specified. Get rid of the `$('body').on('focus', ".datepickerInput", function () {` and initialze your datepicker at pageload with `$('.datepickerInput').datepicker({...`

Comment: I have rows that appear dynamically from code behind though and don't seem to attach to events when they are not using the `.on` method

Comment: I added why I used the `.on` in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use the [`altField` and `altFormat`](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#alt-field) options to autofill an other input.

```js
$('#picker').datepicker({
  altField: '#output',
  altFormat: 'DD'
});
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="picker">
<input type="text" id="output">
```

Comment: I tried, 

`$('body').on('focus', ".datepickerInput", function () {
                    var Day = $("#" + id).closest('tr').find('td:eq(5) input').attr('id');
                    var DayId = "#" + Day;
                    $(this).datepicker({
                        controlType: "select",
                        //onSelect: showDay($(this).attr("id"))
                        altField: DayId,
                        altFormat: 'DD'

                        
                    });
                });`

Comment: @Lapskaus Yeah, I was able to confirm the Id is correct. The datepicker doesn't show up now though

Comment: Does it not like me adding variables before the datepicker? Seems strange that would have to do with anything.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to get id, I added `var id = $(this).attr("id");`, man always missing something small. Thank for the help!